# Stripe iOS SDK - Value of type 'STPPaymentResult' has no member 'source'

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

I am having an issue with my project that is causing it to fail it's build. The error is:

> Value of type 'STPPaymentResult' has no member 'source'

And my code is:

```
  func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    // Create charge using payment result
    let source = paymentResult.source.stripeID
    
    // call api to process payment
    apiTask?.cancel()
    showLoading()
    apiTask = PaymentService.topUpBalance(paymentContext.paymentAmount, stripeSource: source, completion: { (error) in
      completion(error)
    })
  }
```

This used to work but works no longer which is making me wonder if Stripe has changed something with the latest version. I have looked everywhere and haven't found an answer.

Help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Stripe iOS SDK migration guide](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/MIGRATING.md), Source/Token was migrated to PaymentMethod from version 16.0.0 and up for STPPaymentResult and other classes.

As such the line should be changed to:

```
let source = paymentResult.paymentMethod.stripeID
```

You should check out the [docs](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentResult.html) for STPPaymentResult and the ['Migrating to the Payment Intents API'](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration) guide.